# C++: fastest to write vector file to output in normal text mode (not binary) in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, file, text, vector

what will be the fastest way to write a `std::vector` (or any contiguous container for that matter) to a file that's not in binary (i.e. text mode)? In my case, speed is important and the vectors are continuously produced and written to file.

In binary mode it is fairly straight forward since `std::vector` is contiguous in memory. Note i do not want to depend on Boost Serialization. (although i may be forced to if its the most elegant way...). Also I need a sequence of characters to separate elements (i.e. a space)

This is what I'm doing at the moment (is an example) but this is very generic even if I wrote an operator `<<` for a `vector`. Is there a more optimized version of this code or am I left with this?

```
std::ofstream output(...);
...
template <typename T>
write_vec_to_file (const &std::vector<T> v)
{
    for (auto i: v)
        output << i << " ";
    output << "\n";
}
```

As a side question, if one keeps calling `std::cout << ...` is there an overhead just to start `std::cout`? My guess would obviously be yes

Comment: Do you want to also be able to easily read the vector back in, or is this output-only?

Comment: "What is the best optimized way ..." -- What do you imply by "best" and "optimized"? What are we optimizing here? Optimization comes next to correctness. Have we found a *correct* solution here (i.e. can we read (from file) what we wrote (to file))?

Comment: What's the problem? If you write to a file, the "optimization" probably is to buy faster hard disks.

Comment: @BoPersson If i wanted to talk about hardware, I would have asked. I'm simply talking about the code it self. Perhaps "optimizing" code is not the best way to describe it. "make code better" code or whatever you'd like to call it. Take your pick I guess. I'll change the text to make it clearer

Comment: @ArunSaha Optimization was the wrong word. I changed the above to involve the word fastest. To be blunt, is the above code the fastest way to write the vector to file in that format given by the function?

Comment: @woosah - You just don't need to optimize your code when that isn't the bottleneck. Faster code just has to wait longer for the storage device.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for your input. Would you say the above code could be rewritten if with your knowledge it looks like it will be expensive? Given that I have the same storage device and the exact same state of it, Simply writing `output_to_file << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << .. << v[N] << "\n";` would be faster but the size `N` may vary. I guess I'm asking If I'm just stuck with the above ( assuming I stick with C++ file O)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) for example

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Ah, I will test this and see some of the speeds on my machine and get back to you